# How to read client post request body form dart server sent by a client

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post, httpserver

I have a dart server

```
 httpServer = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, myPort);
```

and the client should send a post request with some json data in it's body,
how to read that body

```
..addRouter(fileAddedToShareSpaceEndPoint, HttpMethod.POST,
        (request, response) {
      //? here make a provider to handle peer share space items then update the items if the viewed items are for the updated peer
      var headers = request.headers;
      

      print(headers);
    })
```

I got some answers saying that you can use the following code but I'am getting an error with both

```
var body1 = await request.transform(Utf8Decoder()).join();
// or 
var body2 =  request.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
```

and I am already have a full server setup and it's running so I don't wanna use other library like shelf or other thing because it's gonna be a lot of migration work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind mode parsing req, each new bind req, finishing join()
now you have handle all new bind started request stream in "content"
now you can use content to decode.

```
    String content = await utf8.decoder.bind(req).join();
    var data = jsonDecode(content) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

read this post

https://medium.com/ionicfirebaseapp/handling-a-post-request-in-a-server-in-flutter-4f4bcf1e00b7